# If it's "yourself", why isn't it "hisself"?

Tags: pronouns

There seems to be a bit of inconsistency with "-self" pronouns. Some are possessive while others are objective/subjective:

**Consider:**

> - Yourself
> - Ourselves
> - Itself(?)

**vs:**

> - Himself
> - Herself
> - Themselves
> - Itself(?)

The first set use the possessive pronoun; the second don't. Why?

Similarly, is "itself" "it"+"-self" or "its"+"-[s]elf"?

Comment: Please search the site for questions that have already been answered.

Comment: Well, don't expect much regularity in stuff like this; the usual combining rules don't apply to pronouns. As it happens, first and second person reflexive pronouns are formed from the possessive stem (_my-, our-, your-_), while third person reflexive pronouns are formed from the objective stem (_him-, her-, it-, them-_). It's got two different regular formations instead of one. After all, it's doubly inflected -- plural is marked on **both** parts: _them_ is plural, and so is _selves_ -- so it's got lots of room for irregularity.